# Custom datagridview cell selected

Tags: c#, datagridview

When i'm hitting enter key depends on what datagridview cell is selected to run different code.

Example

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
         if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells = dataGridView1.Cells[0])
         {
           dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];
         }
         if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells = dataGridView1.Cells[1])
         {
           dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[2, 0];
         }
          if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells = dataGridView1.Cells[2])
         {
           form2 ss = new form2();
           ss.ShowDialog();
```

Now i get error Error   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're trying to accomplish, but it should be `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells`

Comment: I want for each different cell, enter key to running different code

Comment: DataGridView does not have Cells property. All the properties it has are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_properties(v=vs.110).aspx). Read a tutorial on how to use DataGridView before you start writing code